# Lighthouse/PSI Score Variability Between Environments

Tags: pagespeed-insights

We're seeing a big discrepancy (around 30 points) in the performance score when we use Lightouse or PSI when we test a site in a test environment v the prod environment. The discrepancy is consistent over many tests.

We're trying to determine the effect of various changes we make to the site on the score. Our understanding is that the tools try to consider network-independent aspects of the site but our results would indicate the network has a big part in the performance score.

The code, db, media, etc. are the same across the two environments.  We removed all third party scripts and are still seeing a big discrepancy. Removing third party scripts increased the score on our test environment but there was no change on the prod environment - in fact, we saw some tests show even lower scores and that didn't make much sense to us.

There are definitely differences in the network setup between the two environments and we're trying to sort through where to focus our efforts. I've found info that would explain varying scores between Lighthouse and PSI but can't find much about how network, hosting, etc. play a part in the score variance.

Any information on how much different versions of IIS or anti-virus could affect the score?

Comment: That is a lot of words to not give us any debug information  Try reading this first: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/variability.md then the best thing to look at is where the recommendations differ and where your score suffers between the two environments. This will nearly always point you to the root cause of the issue (is TBT higher? You JS is loading in a different order perhaps. Is everything higher? Your server is causing a bottleneck, check the Time to First Byte on each network request). Share the two versions of your report if you can so we can help.

Comment: Thank you for the response and I apologize for the word count. Unfortunately, I can't share the debug info so I was trying to understand if network issues can cause such a discrepancy in scores if the code and architecture of the site is the same. The article was helpful!

Comment: If you are still struggling with this you could still share your lighthouse report info without giving any identification information: Share the main 6 categories values and a list of what items appear under "diagnostics" **for both of the sites**. May take a little bit of typing but there is normally enough information there to at least point you to the root cause.